# Run background after submitting a Form in Struts 1.x

Tags: sendmail, struts-1

Iam looking out for a solution to below problem:
        In Strust1.x, after submitting a form , i need to send mail to group which contains around 200 people, in this my page should be redirect to another page , and in back ground sending mail job should be running . As of now iam able to send mails but the page keeps on loading until the mails sent to group .
So please can any one suggest any solution. Do any framework has this kind of functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you name MTA/mail server you use?

Comment: we are using SMPT server

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any special frameworks, just [create new background thread](https://www.google.by/search?q=java+create+background+thread) and forward to desired page, your background thread will continue working:

```
public class MyAction extends Action {

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(final ActionMapping mapping, final ActionForm form,
            final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {

        // start sending emails in background
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO send emails
            }
        };
        thread.start();

        // forward to your desired page
        return mapping.findForward("/yourForward.jsp");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the problem . In my action i initialized one  Thread which takes care of sending emails . Starting and stopping is done in same thread . Page will be redirected and in back ground thread will be running.

Thanks